# Формирование нумерованного списка из значений из json-файла и переменных

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

Есть  функция, реализующая вывод нумерованного списка с данными о работнике и его зарплате.

Необходимо чтобы четвертой строкой в списке выводилась еще и зарплата.

```
function printList(salary){
    $.getJSON("name" + blockNumber + ".json", {"name": " ", "deparment": " ", "post": " "})
        .done(function (json) {
            var output = Mustache.render('<ol><li>{{name}}</li><li>{{department}}</li><li> {{post}}</li></ol>', json);

        })
```

}

Т. е. на выходе должен получиться такой список:

1. name
2. department
3. post
4. salary

Как это получить? Как правильно передать переменную зарплаты, чтобы ее можно было использовать для формирования строки вывода? Ну или, как это сделать, не передавая ее?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function printList(salary){
    $.getJSON("name" + blockNumber + ".json", {"name": " ", "deparment": " ", "post": " "})
        .done(function (json) {
            var tpl = [
                  '<ol>',
                    '<li>{{name}}</li>',
                    '<li>{{department}}</li>',
                    '{% if salary %}'
                      '<li>{{ salary }}</li>',
                    '{% endif %}',
                    '<li>{{post}}</li>',
                  '</ol>',
                ].join('');
      
            return Mustache.render(tpl, json);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не добавить

```
<li>{{salary}}</li>
```

?

Comment: он же не виден внутри done. Так-то понятно

Comment: Нет, мой косяк, все работает